# Hosting react app on godaddy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, hosting

I bought domain and cheapest hosting on GoDaddy, but have no idea how to upload my react app to cPanel.

Uploading simple index.html into public_html works, but I haven't yet found how to proceed with react app.

Here is [the project](https://github.com/Akirtovskis/portfolio-preview) that I want to upload.

In case what I am asking is not possible, I would appreciate any other recommendations on how to get my react app going on domain I just bought.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I need your help if you found a solution to your problem!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to your projects `package.json` file, the production build command is `build:prod`. So if you are using npm run: `npm run build:prod` or if using yarn `yarn build:prod`.

Then your `webpack.config.js` states that the output production javascript `bundle.js` file will be in `public/dist/`. So you need to upload the `public` folder AFTER running the command above to produce `bundle.js`. Make sure that you keep file and folder structure the same when uploading the contents `public` folder.

Comment: @akirtovskis My pleasure, I am glad I a could help!

Comment: Do react routes work alright by this method? Or do you need to add any extra code for that to work?

Comment: Sadly this doesnt work at all. I dont get my production build, instead i get a "launch this page" screen.

Comment: I am confused on the second paragraph of your answer. Can you be more clear with that?

Comment: @Marvin can you please clearly state your issue or what you find confusing so that I can address that directly.

Comment: @Evans So , you are saying we need to run "npm run build:prod" and then upload files to "public_html" in GoDaddy ?